# Is it possible to select all floats on a page with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select all elements that have CSS computed style float:left or float:right. I see attribute selectors available in the JQuery documentation, however I am interested in CSS properties not attributes.

Possible use cases for such a feature would be to select say all display:none elements on a page.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick without class hacking:

```
$("*").filter( function() {
    return /^(left|right)$/.test( $(this).css("float") )
})
```

By the way, jQuery already has a nice way to find all `display: none` elements:

```
$(":hidden")
```

Answer (score 5):

Creating new selectors is kind of fun, so I did that:

**Usage:**

> :hasCssAttr(property, value ...)
>
> `Property` is the css property you would like use to compare
>
> `value` is the value(s) you would like to match against (you can have more than one)

```
$(':hasCssAttr(float, left)').css('float', 'right');
```

The source Luke:

```
$.expr[':'].hasCssAttr = function(objNode, intStackIndex, arrProperties, arrNodeStack) {
  var arrArguments = arrProperties[3].split(','); 
  var cssPropVal = $(objNode).css(arrArguments[0]); // need for speed
  for (var i = 1 ; i < arrArguments.length ; i++)
    if (cssPropVal == arrArguments[ i ].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""))
        return true;      
  return false;
}
```

Basically, this selects any ol' css property. I suppose you could eliminate the loop if you only wanted one value, kind of unnecessary. Also, I wonder if it might be more interesting to do this in an eval so you could do numerical comparisons. Anyway. There it is.

[Props to Ben for helping me out.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1457-How-To-Build-A-Custom-jQuery-Selector.htm)

Comment: +1 for making your own flexible selector. I always prefer flexible solutions when possible.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to apply the floating style via CSS then you could select on the class name and do a show/hide as necessary.

```
 <style>
    .right { float: right; }
    .left { float: left; }
 </style>

 <div class='left'>...</div>
 <div class='right'>...</div>

  $('.left,.right').hide();
```

Comment: $('.left.right') would be empty in this case, since you're looking for elements with both classes. Did you mean $('.left, .right')?

Comment: The interesting bit is that I had it that way originally and then must have misread the documentation.  Yes, the comma needs to be there.